# ValidateAntiForgeryToken with Hperlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I use MVC4, I know we can use ValidateAntiForgeryToken in Form with Post method. I want to know if it is possible to use ValidateAntiForgeryToken in hyperlink????

For security problem, I want to make sure the page is coming from Page 1 to Page 2, so that is why I want Validate the Hyperlink.

If Yes, how can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that the ValidateAntiForgeryToken is what you are looking for.  The MVC implementation creates a token and stores that in session.  That token is valid for the user for the lifetime of the session, and it isn't designed to be used on a form by form basis.

What you will probably want to do is create this token yourself.  When you generate Page 1, create a token and store it in session.  You can use the anchor and append the token in the link.  This way you can use a get.  Page 2 could validate the token and then remove it from the session.

Please remember that if you put anything in the get variables, you run the risk of someone bookmarking that page (with the GET variable).

Alternatively, you can use POST and have the anchor call some javascript to complete the call.  This of course does not work on browsers that don't support JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want page two to only be accessible per visit of page one, you can use TempData for this.

```
    public ActionResult PageOne()
    {
        TempData["FromPageOne"] = true;
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult PageTwo()
    {
        //values in TempData are only accessible once 
        //so user must always come from PageOne
        if ((bool?)TempData["FromPageOne"] == true) 
        {
            //From page one!
        }
        else
        {
            //Came directly, from another URL, or was refreshed (F5)
        }
        return View();
    }
```